# CakePHP - Use jQuery to check if user is logged in thru Auth

Tags: jquery, cakephp, authentication

How can I find out if a user is logged in CakePHP thru the Auth component using jQuery. If a user is logged in allow the action to execute if not display an alert asking the user to log in.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".voteup").click(function() {
            // var isLoggedIn = ... code needed
            if(isLoggedIn){
                var Id = $(this).children("p").text();
                $(this).children("#article_thumbsUp").load("/comments/voteup/"+Id);
            }else{
                alert('You must be logged in to vote on a comment');
            }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to do so after the page is rendered? It is common to that on the server before serving the page.

Comment: From what I understand, you're already doing checking in cakePHP to make sure they're logged in, but you want to show people that they can rate things up regardless of whether they're logged in or not. I imagine that you do checking on the server side too to check that they are logged in when they click to vote up too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `CommentsController` with an action `check_login()`

```
public function check_login() {

    // $this->Auth->user() returns NULL or User info for logged in user
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {

        // your user is logged in echo success
        ...

    } else {

        // you user is NOT logged in echo failure
        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: This is for the controller which I know how to do. However, I wanted to know how to call this action in jQuery and act according. Thanks

Comment: @CaboOne Well, you would do it the same way you're doing the request for `voteup` in jQuery.  Make 2 AJAX requests or, the better way imo, simply have the code set in your `voteup` action to check for login status and if they aren't logged in spit back a JSON response that lets you know to build a register button or something.  There's no way to verify whether a user is logged in strictly through jQuery.  You have to hit the server to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use javascript for this, it's not safe at all. You should check this server-side, in the controller, as shown in the answer by Charles Sprayberry.

Then in javascript you always do the Ajax request (use `$.get` with a callback), and check the response to display the alert or update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem with the following suggestion. So thanks guys for your help...

commments_controller.php

```
public function checklogin() {          
    $this->autoRender = false; 
    if ($this->Auth->user()) {
        $loggedIn = 1;
    } else {
        $loggedIn = 0;
    }
    return $loggedIn;
}
```

jQuery Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var isLoggedIn = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/comments/checklogin",
    success: function(msg){
        isLoggedIn = msg;
    }
});
$(".voteup").click(function() {
    if(isLoggedIn == 1){
        var Id = $(this).children("p").text();
        $(this).children("#article_thumbsUp").load("/comments/voteup/"+Id);
    }else{
        alert('You must be logged in to vote');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

It works nicely... I am not sure if it is the best one but it works